# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in connect.php

Tags: php

I am trying to teach myself PHP and I've come unstuck at a very early stage, I'm trying to connect to my db with the following code:

```
$server = 'server';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$database = 'database';

if(!mysqli_connect($server, $username,  $password))
{
exit('Error: could not establish database connection');
}
if(!mysqli_select_db($database)
{
exit('Error: could not select the database');
}
```

However, when I run this code I get the following error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in connect.php on line 22

If I comment out the final if statement the error goes away.

I have tried Google etc, but I feel that my lack of knowledge/experience means that I might not recognise the solution just from scouring random search results.

As a side note, Visual Studio is also giving me a sytax error on the final semi colon.

Comment: You're missing a `)` at the end of your second `if`.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18050071/3933332

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I missed something so obvious. That link has been added to my book marks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typos:

```
if(!mysqli_select_db($database)
  ^--open #1        ^--open #2
                              ^---close #2 
}
```

you never close #1... e.g. you're missing a `)`.

Comment: Don't we have already enough dupes for this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a bracket in your last if statement?

```
if(!mysqli_select_db($database)
```

should be

```
if(!mysqli_select_db($database))
```

P.S. Try use an editor that *warns* you of these bracket errors. Like when you select one bracket it highlights the pairing bracket or groups code blocks. This helps finds time consuming bugs like this.